# Subclass Initialization Issue with Data not from Superclass

Tags: python, numpy, oop

I'm having an issue trying to make a rectangle class that is subclassed from a Points class, which (bare with me) is subclassed from nd.array.

I'm aware (or so I think) of the nuances of subclassing an nd.array. What i'm trying to achieve is being able to construct a rectangle with a center point, height, width, and rotation and not need to directly feed in discrete points. Below is my implementation of the rectangle constructor, the @init_args wrapper takes type hinted inputs and calls the class constructor which works. It appears that it isn't even getting into the `__init__` method and jumps straight to the Points `__new__()` method.

```
class Points(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, list_of_points):
        if type(list_of_points) == 'numpy.ndarray':
            obj = list_of_points
        else:
            obj = np.vstack(list_of_points).view(cls)
        return obj

class Rectangle(Points):
    @init_args
    def __init__(self, rect_attributes: RectAttributes):
        self.points = np.zeros((4, 2))
        print('in rect constructor')
        self.attributes = rect_attributes
        self.construct_rect_from_attributes()
        super().__init__(self.points)
```

I don't think I really need the `super().__init__ call`, I was just hoping that it would delay the Points constructor. What I really need is just to be able to initialize the rectangle with attributes that aren't contained in the superclass.

Comment: `__new__` is called first, before `__init__` gets called. Since `Rectangle.__new__` is not defined, then `Points.__new__` is used. Once that returns a value, *then* that value is passed to `Rectangle.__init__` (assuming `Points.__new__` returns an instance of `Rectangle`, which isn't obvious to me.)

Comment: This is also wrong: `type(list_of_points) == 'numpy.ndarray'`.  `type()` returns the actual class of an object, not the name of the class.  You probably want `isinstance(list_of_points, np.ndarray)` or, if you want to accept only exactly the `ndarray` class (and not subclasses thereof) you can use `type(list_of_points) is np.ndarray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of chepner is make sense.  Another thing that's confusing to me as that you want `Rectangle` to be a subclass of `ndarray`, yet you assign to it a `self.points` (initialized to zeros) of a *different* ndarray.  `ndarray.__new__` itself constructs the array and its data, so your `Rectangle` class is essentially already constructed from the `list_of_points` passed to `Points.__new__`.

Meanwhile you have a `self.points` that has no association with the points passed to the constructor.

From your example it's not clear what `rect_attributes` is supposed to be or what `construct_rect_from_attributes()` is supposed to do.  But I think what you probably want is something like this (and IMO you should allow construction of `Rectangle` from a list of points as well, but that's up to whatever your requirements are):

```
class Rectangle(Points):
    # put in the type hints anything else array-like
    def __new__(cls, data: Union[list, np.ndarray, RectAttributes]):  
        if isinstance(data, RectAttributes):
            # assuming you want to store the original attributes somewhere
            self.attributes = data
            # rect_from_attributes should be a classmethod and
            # should return an array of points
            data = cls.rect_from_attributes(data)
        else:
            # a default value if the rect was constructed another
            # way, or inversely construct a RectAttributes from points
            self.attributes = ...
        return super().__new__(cls, data)
```

Comment: I originally had the Rectangle class able to be constructed with either a series of points or the rect_attributes (center, width, height, rotation) and found for the application(vision) the construction from points was not necessary.

Comment: I'd like rectangle to be a "kind-of" relation to the Points class because I have methods that i'd like to also utilize that are generic to points(like translate, scale, rotate), while maintaining the wealth of numpy functions i can operate directly on the Rect class.

I apologize for the confusion, i'm a little new to the subclassing idea and in particular with numpy arrays.

Comment: The above will work for either case then.  If you just care about rect_attributes you can simplify it with just the first clause in the `if` statement.

Comment: To be clear, the key here is to convert from `RectAttributes` to an array of points, and use `super().__new__(cls, points)` to call the subclass's `__new__` with that array.